# difference between thoughtworks and openqa selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between `openqa.selenium` and `thoughtworks.selenium`? How are they compatible with each other?

There is no class Selenium in package `openqa.selenium`, but there is class `WebDriver`. I want to use webElement in my test, which imports thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium.

Some tutorials use `openqa.selenium`, other `thoughtworks.selenium`, and I am completely confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- *thoughtworks.selenium* is the original Selenium (aka Selenium 1, or Selenium-RC).
- *openqa.selenium* is Selenium 2 aka Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: Thanks. Want to add that Selenium WebDriver is the successor of Selenium Remote Control **which has been officially deprecated**, as it mentioned [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).